# wp-admin remove the subfolder URL

Tags: wp-admin

I have a problem with WP. I have a website with this URL: http://sub.domain.com/subfolder My Website works fine, but when I connect on wp-admin, the subfolder URL disappeared (http://sub.domain.com/wp-admin). I don't understand why the subfolder disappears ?

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: You have probably configured [a virtual home directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) - the WordPress installation is in the root folder of your website, but is serving the front-end under `/subfolder`

Comment: Yes, WP is installed in my root folder (`/var/www/`), but I already seen the Codex article, it was not of much use. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: I'm not sure how much clearer I can make it - you have WordPress installed in root, but are serving the frontend under a sub-directory. That's why the frontend is `/subfolder` and the backend is `/wp-admin`

Comment: OK, I understand. I can add a folder in my root, and keep the index.php and .htacces in the root.