# wp-admin remove part of the url

Tags: wp-admin, urls, nginx, docker

This looks like [wp-admin remove the subfolder URL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226912/wp-admin-remove-the-subfolder-url) but it's not the same problem, because the subfolder part is not a subfolder.

I'm working on a clean VM as a host for Docker containers. I have a dockerized Wordpress listening on 8080 on the VM.

I can hit Wordpress at `http://<vm_ip>:8080` and install just fine. It takes me to the backend at `http://<vm_ip>:8080/wp-admin/` and everything works as expected.

Now I'd like to access my blog at `http://<vm_ip>/blog/` so I set up nginx on the VM to proxy requests per location :

```
upstream blog {
    server localhost:8080;
}
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name <vm_ip> localhost;

    location /blog/ {
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Nginx-Proxy    true;
        proxy_pass        http://blog/;
    }
}
```

> *This is temporary as nginx will probably end up dockerized, but that requires custom images ; one thing at a time...*
>   *Also with an actual domain name, I would use subdomains so that would take care of my problem*

I hit `http://<vm_ip>/blog/` and I get to the install, but the static files' url are not correct : `http://blog/wp-includes/css/...` so the UI is a bit raw.

I move on with the install. It works and takes me to `http://<vm_ip>/blog/wp-admin/install.php?step=2` but the Connect button points to `http://blog/wp-login.php` so I get a 404.

I need to make a change directly in the db : *site_url* and *home* (in  `wp_options`) are set to `http://blog` so I update them both to `http://<vm_ip>/blog`.

Now the frontend works just fine, but the backend has problems. While most links are OK, some buttons' href miss the *blog* part : `http://<vm_ip>/wp-admin` so it takes me nowhere.

Those buttons usually have some kind of submit role :

- the close button (top left) in Appearance > Customize (points to `http://wp-admin/`)
- the Save button in Settings > General (submit for `<form action="options.php">`)

What's funny is it's not consistent : the Save button on Page > Add works just fine (though it throws a DOMException : `Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://blog/wp-admin/post.php?post=15&action=edit' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://<vm_ip>' and URL 'http://<vm_ip>/blog/wp-admin/post.php?post=15&action=edit&message=1'`)

Is it something with the `site_url`and `home`options ?

Should I search the admin templates for the incomplete urls placeholders ?

Is there some hook or filter to force the right url ?

Answer (score 0):

I've searched in the admin templates. It seems the placeholders rely on the functions  `wp_get_referer()` and `wp_get_raw_referer()` which use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and a wp custom variable passed in the request : `$_REQUEST['_wp_http_referer']`.

So Wordpress builds some URLs (apparently not all) on `REQUEST_URI`, that is `/wp-admin/whatever` (in the backend). The logs show that `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` comes through regularly, so it's hitting the right URL.

So I guess it has to do with the headers nginx passes through.

*(That kind of answers my question as far as WP is concerned. If I need to ask on a nginx forum, I'll link it here.)*

I tried various rewritings and if, to no avail.

But I'm closing in : the `http://<vm_ip>/wp-admin/...` requests are handled by nginx on the VM, in the  `/` location block, so the `/blog/` location block never gets them and they're never proxied to my WP container.

It seems that `try_files` does the trick, at least partly :

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /blog$uri;
}
```

That means that when the `/` location catches a request, it will first try to find a file matching the URI, then a file matching `/blog` + URI, which goes to the `/blog/` location block and to my WP container.

So now, great, when I click on one of the faulty buttons, I'm redirected to my WP container.

Victory !? Not quite yet, because I need to log back in. And the URL is weird : `http://<vm_ip>/blog/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2Foptions-general.php&reauth=1` - if you look at the `redirect_to` part, it is now `http://blog/wp-admin`...
Hence, when I log back in, it takes me to the Dashboard.

However, the form's data has been saved in the meantime. Yes, making progress !

Deep down in the bottom, shouldn't Wordpress **always** use the same logic to build URLs used in the backend and the frontend ? Isn't that some kind of bug ?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?